# Magento - js variable category_info_tabsJsTabs - what is this?

Tags: magento

I'm trying to reverse engineer some functionality in the admin area but I've come up against a problem. When my custom version of the code runs it fails on this next line, saying that category_info_tabsJsTabs is not defined

if (category_info_tabsJsTabs.activeTab) {

which was originally in the template file adminhtml_catalog_category_tree.phtml

I've done a text search for this string but I cant seem to find it anywhere and therefore figure out where it was declared. Can anyone help on this?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That particular variable is declared in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?> = new varienTabs('<?php echo $this->getId() ?>', '<?php echo $this->getDestElementId() ?>', '<?php echo $this->getActiveTabId() ?>', <?php echo $this->getAllShadowTabs()?>);
</script>
```

The method `getJsObjectName()` belongs to the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs`. It looks like this:

```
public function getJsObjectName()
{
    return $this->getId() . 'JsTabs';
}
```

The ID is then set by each descendent of the tabs class, in this case it is `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs` which does this:

```
$this->setId('category_info_tabs');
```

Comment: Hi ClockWorkGeek,

Thanks for pointing that out. That's definately helped me in trying to understand whats going on.

The fact that the variable name is concatenated in the getJsObjectName explains why I couldnt find it with a text search.

If I'm assuming correctly, this means that the getJsObjectName resolves getId() to 'tabs' - thus making 'tabsJsTabs'. I'm guessing that the getId method simply uses the template name - ie tabs(.phtml) ?

Just to complete the picture for me though, where is the 'category_info_' part of the variable name being constructed?

Thanks again for your help,
Ian

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same stuff, so thought to add location of 'category_info_tabs' here:
./app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php